# Mongodb aggregate facet won't work using _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, facet, objectid

I have the following image below

[image]

[image]

I use ***_id*** but won't work but, when I use field like ***field_name*** is working.

I already use ObjectId("5f311...") still no luck

But when I use the query in robomongo client but using ObjectId("5f311...") it works.

I highly appreciate the help from you guys. I spent hours on this.

Thank you and keep safe.

Comment: you have to convert your string object id to object id when query or try `{ _id: { $toObjectId: "your string id" } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ObjectId of mongo like this:

{ $match: { _id: mongo.ObjectId("5f43ebb18415f39cf1cd75d4") } }

complete example:

```
let mongo = require("mongodb");

let dbname = "test";
let mongoServerUrl = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/" + dbname;

const connect = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongo.connect(
      mongoServerUrl,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      },
      (err, client) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          let database = client.db(dbname);
          resolve(database);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};

connect()
  .then((database) => {
    console.log("connect to database");

    database
      .collection("new")
      .aggregate([
        {
          $facet: {
            query1: [
              { $match: { _id: mongo.ObjectId("5f43ebb18415f39cf1cd75d4") } },
            ],
            query2: [
              { $match: { _id: mongo.ObjectId("5f43ebb78415f39cf1cd75d5") } },
            ],
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("get new done");
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res[0].query1);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: use $toObjectId, for ex: { $toObjectId: "$_id" }! might this help you